# Problem related polynomial ring over finite field of intergers

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, finite-fields

if $f(x)$ is in $F[x]$.  $F$ is field of integer mod $p$. $p$ is prime and $f(x)$ is irreducible over $F$ of degree $n$ . prove that $F[x]/(f(x))$ is a field with $p^n$ elements.

Comment: I have approached by considering F[x] as Euclidean Ring.
Also I have considered the Field formed by Quotient group of

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the irreducibility of $f(x)$, the quotient $F[x]/(f(x))$ is a field.

Show that distinct polynomials in $F[x]$ of degree $<n$ are inequivalent modulo $(f(x))$. This will follow from the fact that the polynomial ring $F[x]$ is an Euclidean domain.

This reduces the problem to counting the number of polynomials of degree $<n$ over $F$, which is straightforward.